# wkhtmltopdf-django dynamic template to render

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

Is there any way to generate a PDF dynamically, with content being fetched from the database?

My goal is to allow my users to generate their own PDF design from a wysiwyg editor.

This is my model

```py
    class DocumentService(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
        html_content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I use django-wkhtmltopdf to render html to PDF.

```py
    response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template="document.html",
            filename=filename,
            context=data,
            show_content_in_browser=True,
            cmd_options=cmd_options,
        )
```

How can I render the content of this record into my PDF?

```py
    document = DocumentService.objects.get(pk=1)
    document.html_content # <-- this content
```

The HTML content should be something like this

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <strong>Date: </strong> {{date}}
      <strong>User: </strong> {{user.name}}
      <strong>Email: </strong> {{user.email}}
      <strong>Info: </strong> {{user.info}}
      ...
    </p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [**`engines.from_string(template_code)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine.from_string)

```
from django.template import engines

document = DocumentService.objects.get(pk=1)
data = {'data': document.html_content}
str_template = render_to_string("document.html", data) 
response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template= engines['django'].from_string(str_template),
            filename=filename,
            context=data,
            show_content_in_browser=True,
            cmd_options=cmd_options,
        )
```

and inside your **document.html** you've to add like this

```
<body>
 {{data|safe}} <!--- Use safe if you want to render html --->
</body>
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested, but it throws me the next error:


[Errno 36] File name too long: '/app/src/templates/<!doctype html>\r\n<html lang="es">\r\n\r\n<head>\r\n    


It seems that the function is expecting only the name

Comment: Hello Ankit, with "render" I got this error:
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'HttpResponse'

But, taking your original code, and using like this:
str_template = render_to_string("document.html", data)
template = engines['django'].from_string(str_template)

It works perfect!